# Is it possible to use KnockoutJS with a masked input?

Tags: knockout.js, maskedtextbox

I´m using that plugin : https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney to format my money editor...

I tried to use KnockoutJS in that editor, but it does not work... Without that mask all works fine...

My code test is simple :

```
<input id="Price" data-bind="value: Price"  type="text"  name="Price">
```

Javascript to Mask input

```
$("#Price").maskMoney({ symbol: 'R$ ', showSymbol: true, thousands: '.', decimal: ',', symbolStay: false });
```

And KnockoutJS

```
var ViewModel = function () {
            this.Price = ko.observable();

            this.PriceFinal= ko.computed(function () {
                return this.Price() 
            }, this);
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use a writable computed observable.

```
function MyViewModel() {
    this.price = ko.observable(25.99);

    this.formattedPrice = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return '$' + this.price().toFixed(2);
        },
        write: function (value) {
            // Strip out unwanted characters, parse as float, then write the raw data back to the underlying "price" observable
            value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
            this.price(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value); // Write to underlying storage
        },
        owner: this
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Comment: If you're doing something like this in conjunction with the mapping plugin, create this property as something empty, like $.noop(), then map, apply logic similar to above, and THEN bind

Comment: Why not use a Knockout extender?

Answer (score 14):

You can also register a binding handler for MaskMoney with Knockout, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

ko.bindingHandlers.currencyMask = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().currencyMaskOptions || {};
        $(element).maskMoney(options);

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'focusout', function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();

            var numericVal = parseFloat($(element).val().replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ''));
            numericVal = isNaN(numericVal) ? 0 : numericVal;

            observable(numericVal);
        });

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).unmaskMoney();
        });
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        $(element).val(value);
        $(element).trigger('focus');
    }
};
```

});

and then as your binding:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="currencyMask: MyModel.TotalCost, currencyMaskOptions: { symbol: '$', showSymbol: true, thousands: ',', precision: 0 }" />
```

Note that I tweaked the MaskMoney plugin slightly to use `input.on('focusout.maskMoney', blurEvent);` rather than `input.bind('blur.maskMoney',blurEvent);` because it was not triggering an update on losing focus via mouse clicking, only on tabbing.

I'm new to Knockout and have been finding the binding handler approach really nice for plugins like this and datepickers, etc.

Comment: This is the preferred method IMO.  I have used this code and it worked great.

Comment: I think it would be better to call `$(element).maskMoney('mask');` instead of `$(element).trigger('focus');` in update function since focus event causes unnecessary and unintentional focus

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery.formatcurrency you could do:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.currencyMask = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().currencyMaskOptions || {};
        $(element).formatCurrency(options);
        $(element).keyup(function () {
            $(element).formatCurrency(options);
        });


        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'focusout', function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).val());
        });

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).formatCurrency('destroy');
        });
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        $(element).val(value);
        $(element).trigger('focus');
    }
};

<input data-bind="currencyMask: priceVal, currencyMaskOptions: { roundToDecimalPlace: 0 }" />
```